# How to disable scrolling header in table on concrete example?

Tags: html, css

Could you help me disable scrolling header of table in this concrete example, I have a problem with this. Being honestly I have no idea how to do it.

Construction of my very simple code is:

```
<div id="container">
  <table border="1">
      <thead>
          <th>Short fs [dsa]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>                                                                                           
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Short fs[dsadas]</th>
          <th>Very long long long long long</th>
       </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2avm4a6n/109/

Comment: do you mean having a fixed header that would always be visible?

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper could you show some example ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty common thing to do, [Checkout this pen](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu) - I did not write this

```css
.fixed_headers {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_headers th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed_headers th,
.fixed_headers td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 350px;
}
.fixed_headers thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.fixed_headers tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.old_ie_wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.old_ie_wrapper tbody {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- IE < 10 does not like giving a tbody a height.  The workaround here applies the scrolling to a wrapped <div>. -->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<div class="old_ie_wrapper">
<!--<![endif]-->

<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grape</td>
      <td>Purple / Green</td>
      <td>These are purple and green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>These are yellow.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwi</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>These are Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Watermelon</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tomato</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cantelope</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honeydew</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Papaya</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Raspberry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>These are blue.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passion Fruit</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```